# UWP Is there anyway to implement control for resizing, and move textbox in Canvas?

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp, controls, uwp-xaml

I'm new to UWP canvas element. From the moment I have been finding the way to implement it. I have found this link [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part) which implementing the control that I want. However I follow the class that define in it. I can't inherit the Thumb control which showing it is Sealed type. Is there anyone know how to find a way out to implement this?

```
public class MoveThumb : Thumb
{

    public MoveThumb(Control dataContext, DragDeltaEventHandler dragDelta)
    {
        DataContext = dataContext;
        DragDelta = dragDelta;
    }

    public Control DataContext { get; private set; }
    public DragDeltaEventHandler DragDelta { get; }

    private void MoveThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Control designerItem = this.DataContext as Control;

        if (designerItem != null)
        {
            double left = Canvas.GetLeft(designerItem);
            double top = Canvas.GetTop(designerItem);

            Canvas.SetLeft(designerItem, left + e.HorizontalChange);
            Canvas.SetTop(designerItem, top + e.VerticalChange);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I've got some sample. Think you'll get the idea. Here's `UserControl` XAML:

```
Width="256"
Height="128">

<Grid x:Name="ContainerGrid" Background="Transparent"
      ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY"
      ManipulationStarted="Manipulator_OnManipulationStarted"
      ManipulationDelta="Manipulator_OnManipulationDelta">

    <Viewbox IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <TextBlock Text="Text" Foreground="Lime"/>
    </Viewbox>

    <Rectangle x:Name="ResizeRectangle" IsHitTestVisible="False"
               Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Orange" 
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

    <Rectangle Stretch="Fill" Stroke="DeepPink" StrokeThickness="2"
               IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
</Grid>
```

And a code behind:

```
    private bool _isResizing;

    public Manipulator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Manipulator_OnManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Position.X > Width - ResizeRectangle.Width && e.Position.Y > Height - ResizeRectangle.Height) _isResizing = true;
        else _isResizing = false;
    }

    private void Manipulator_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isResizing)
        {
            Width += e.Delta.Translation.X;
            Height += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(this, Canvas.GetLeft(this) + e.Delta.Translation.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(this, Canvas.GetTop(this) + e.Delta.Translation.Y);
        }
    }
```

After creating this `UserControl` just place it into your `Canvas`:

```
<Canvas>
    <local:Manipulator/>
</Canvas>
```

I called it Manipuilator.

And here's how it looks like:

[image]