# UWP: Creating a movable+resizable control

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP project that acts as a dashboard, but I have been unable to produce a solution on how to make my dashboard widgets movable and resizable. I have tried a few things:

- Grid with ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY,Scale". I was not able to change the cursor into Move/Resize to indicate manipulation, and it was not foolproof. Dragging the mouse too fast lost focus on the resize/move.
- GridSplitters. The splitters themselves did not look that good, they did not resize accordingly with the window.

My aim is to be able to show the move cursor when howering over the widget's "title", and show a resize cursor when hovering over a widget's edges.

Is this doable in UWP?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a movable and resizable control, you could create a UserControl and place some elements in the grid to customize the layout. Then you could implement [ManipulationStarted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationstarted?view=winrt-20348) event and [ManipulationDelta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationdelta?view=winrt-20348) event for this grid(ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY").

Please refer to [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397647/uwp-is-there-anyway-to-implement-control-for-resizing-and-move-textbox-in-canva/48401652) to know the detailed code.